# Class property object converted into string

Tags: python, string, properties, type-conversion

For a project i need to get information from a website. I wanted to to write a class to deal with that part in isolation.

Right now I'm getting the contents of the HTML through the request model and use this:

```
def get_line(self):
       for line in self.r.iter_lines():
              self.i = self.i+1
              if self.i == self.zeile:
                    return str(line)
              elif self.i > self.zeile:
                    break
```

function to get a specific line of HTML. Now I wanted to save the content of line in a variable, and used this:

```
temp_string = property(get_line)
```

The problem is now that I have a property object not a string, but to cut the content of this HTML down further I want to use the `.find` method to dynamically get the start and end point where to cut the string.

If I convert the property into a string, though, it changes the HTML (which was perfectly shown before when printing it to console) into this:

```
<property object at 0x0000020208A5D818>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So... why did you call `property`?

Comment: Well, you created a property. A property is an object that'll call the underlying function for you when you try to access the property *on an instance*. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: well i saw the property used on a website in conjungtion with getters and setters for classes so i thought i could dynamically create the variable inside the class so when i instance it i would only need to access the result attribute without any methodcalling. basically put all the working bits in the blackbox and only care about the result.

Answer (score 0):

That... isn't what a property is for or how you use it.

`get_line` already returns a string. If you want the result, then just call it on your instance:

```
line = my_instance.get_line()
```

Comment: my goal was to compute the variable line before instancing, so that everything is kept inside the object and i simply instance the class once and already have the result i want in a variable without more actions.

Comment: no idea how to edit my comment so i have to use another comment. question is, are classes and objects the best way to do that or are there simpler ways? or do i need something like an actionobject that does all the computing inside it?

Comment: But how could that work? Your logic depends on instance values, so how could you calculate it before creating an instance?

Comment: so first of all i have to admit im fairly new to programming and this is my first dabble with oop so i dont know everything. what i thought could be possible was: put down the plans inside the class and when i instance the class with the specific url the class at that point in time then knows what it has to do to give me the result i want. does that mean i have to write a function to call all the methods of the instanced object to get to my result? there is no way to put that work inside the class itself?

Comment: welp i worked a bit more on the code and i got it work the way i want it now. i added another method main() that calls the get_line method, changed the get_line method to set self.temp_string = line and created a function outside the class that handles initilizing the object, calling the main method and than simply returning the result. atleast i now know how to do it next time XD